# JSF - PrimeFaces 6 + Protocol Buffer does not have a writable property clientid error

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, protocol-buffers, el

I'm working with PrimeFaces 6.1 and google protocol buffers 3.
When I try to write with a form directly into a protocol buffer builder object it's return this error:

> javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /pages/twap/management.xhtml
>   @425,29 value="#{twapManagmentController.addTwapOrder.clientId}": The
>   class
>   'com.companyname.libs.data.dictionary.algos.AlgosProtos$TwapOrder$Builder'
>   does not have a writable property 'clientId'.

Jsf page is not able to find the setters of proto builder class
I have declared the attribute in my bean as builder in the next way:

```
private TwapOrder.Builder addTwapOrder;

public TwapOrder.Builder getAddTwapOrder() {
    return addTwapOrder;
}

public void setAddTwapOrder(TwapOrder.Builder addTwapOrder) {
    this.addTwapOrder = addTwapOrder;
}
```

And Mi Jsf Code is:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Account" for="account" />
<p:inputText id="account" value="·{twapManagmentController.addTwapOrder.clientId}"
            style="width:150px" />
```

Any advice on how to make it directly with proto object is welcome
thanks.

Comment: Properties need to have a 'setter' and 'getter'. In this case a `getClientId()` and `setClientId(<type> clientId)`. So all the code you post above does not help anything, it does not make clear if there is one or not. And please in cases like this, try plain jsf counterparts. `h:inputText`. Will most likely not work either.,

Comment: Maybe you don't get what is protocols buffer of google, its generates for you all getters and setters for that im not publishing thats part of the code, because its self generate for the library